# The best CLI parser for Java

Tags: java, command-line

What CLI parser for Java is easy to use and more scalable than others?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here are some of the most popular. They are all pretty feature complete, and having used the top two I can recommend them.

- **Commons CLI**
  http://commons.apache.org/cli/
- **Java Gems**
  http://code.google.com/p/javagems/
- **picocli** (with colorized usage help and autocomplete)
  http://picocli.info/
- **JArgs**
  http://jargs.sourceforge.net/
- **GetOpt**
  http://www.urbanophile.com/arenn/hacking/download.html

EDIT: For completeness, here are some others I've come across

- **JOpt Simple**
  http://jopt-simple.sourceforge.net/
- **Args4J**
  https://args4j.dev.java.net/
- **ArgParser**
  http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~lloyd/java/argparser.html
- **Natural CLI**
  http://naturalcli.sourceforge.net/
- **TE-Code**
  http://te-code.sourceforge.net/
- **JSAP**
  http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/
- **CLAJR**
  http://clajr.sourceforge.net/
- **CmdLn**
  http://ostermiller.org/utils/CmdLn.html
- **JewelCli**
  http://jewelcli.sourceforge.net/
- **JCommando**
  http://jcommando.sourceforge.net/
- **Parse-cmd**
  http://code.google.com/p/parse-cmd/

Comment: Thx. Now i'll use the Commons CLI, because i like Appache's products

Comment: Good choice. You can always rely on Apache Commons to be rock solid implementations.

Comment: The best implementation is **Jargs** at https://github.com/purcell/jargs  
Straightforward, logical, not bloaded with 1 file & 600 SLOC.   
Easy to get the remaining args too: 

  String[] otherArgs = parser.getRemainingArgs();

Comment: You can also find libraries tagged with "Command Line Parsers" in [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/open-source/command-line-parsers)

Answer (score 4):

**JLine** is a library for building shell-like applications in Java.

- Groovy is using it for it's shell implementation : [`groovysh`](http://groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html).
- JLine is also used by [OpenTelegard/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenTelegard/2) (JRuby).

Since 2002, the project was hosted on [SourceForge.net](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) and last release was [JLine-1.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jline/files/jline/) on April 2011.

But in 2009, the project has started the [migration to GitHub.com](http://jline.github.io/jline2/) and has [released the series 2.x](https://github.com/jline/jline2/releases) since November 2009 (version 2.0). Last version 2.x when writing this answer is 2.14.2 in May 2016.

In October 2016, a new [series 3.x has been released](https://github.com/jline/jline3/releases).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think scalability is a factor here. you want something which is feature complete and easy to use.
I mostly use [jargs](http://jargs.sourceforge.net/) but I generally dislike it's API (using it out of habit).

you can also try [java getopt](http://www.urbanophile.com/arenn/hacking/download.html) impl, which I did not personally used.

Comment: I remember when we used JArgs we wrote our own interface to wrap around its API. It worked fine but wasn't as easy to use as it might have been.