# acccepting file names using command line in java

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to accept 3 filenames through a command line. This is the code I tried but not working.. ?? Pls help

```
public class MedicalStudentMatcher {

enum Arguments {
    HospitalFile, ResidentFile, OutputFile
};

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Retrieve file locations from command line arguments
    String hospitalFile = "";
    String residentFile = "";
    String outFile = "";


    if (args.length > 2){
        hospitalFile = args[Arguments.HospitalFile.ordinal()];
        residentFile = args[Arguments.ResidentFile.ordinal()];
        outFile = args[Arguments.OutputFile.ordinal()];
    } else {
        System.out
                .println("Please include names for the preference files and output file when running the application.\n "
                        + "Usage: \n\tjava MedicalStudentMatcher hospital.csv student.csv out.txt\n");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Are you passing the names in the command line?

Comment: well, it goes to the else loop.. it not accepting values

Comment: you mean `else branch`, anyway, `args[Arguments.HospitalFile.ordinal()]` is over-egineered. You better use a command-line argument parser if you cannot live with plain integer index. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524661/the-best-cli-parser-for-java

Comment: seriously consider using something like commons-cli http://commons.apache.org/cli/

Comment: I did try the integer index.. it still jumped to "else" without entering the "if" branch

Comment: How did you run the program?  Also, you might try printing out `args.length` to see if it's what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some debugging.  Print the length of you command line arguments as well as each argument

something like:

```
System.out.println(args.length);

for(String arg: args)
{
   System.out.println(arg);
}
```

This way you will see what you are passing to your program as arguments.

Comment: thanks.. tried that and the length of the argument is 0... dont know why.. that's where I'm stuck at

Comment: how are you running you application.  are running it from command prompt/ console?

Comment: @user3438489 right click where? Are you inside Eclipse or some other IDE?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: You have to pass file names as arguments to your java main class. Test your code first with running it in command line. If your are using an IDE try to find arguments in run configurations.

Comment: In eclipse, right click on you project, select "Run As"-> "Run Configurations" . Select "(x)=Arguments" tab and enter the list of your files under Program arguments

Comment: Upvotes for you because I answered another of his questions and got no upvote love either. :)